# Unable to save file to s3 using scala akka-http

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, akka, akka-http

Trying to save a file to s3. File is coming in as a `Source[ByteString, Any]` so having to convert it to an `InputStream` for the `PutObjectRequest`. Then calculating the `ObjectMetadata` content length and md5. Here's my code followed by the error message. Any input would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
def uploadFile(source: Source[ByteString, _]) = {

  val stream: InputStream = source.runWith(StreamConverters.asInputStream(FiniteDuration(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)))

  val metadata = new ObjectMetadata()
  metadata.setContentLength(IOUtils.toByteArray(stream).length)
  metadata.setContentMD5(Base64.encodeBase64(DigestUtils.md5(stream)).toString)

  s3.putObject(new PutObjectRequest("bucketName", "key", stream, metadata))
}
```

Stack trace error message: `com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception with message The Content-MD5 you specified was invalid.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A non-blocking, more [reactive](http://www.reactive-streams.org) alternative would be to use [Alpakka S3](http://developer.lightbend.com/docs/alpakka/latest/s3.html) sink.

It would solve all your encoding and S3 protocol issues for you, plus it will be fully backpressure-enabled for an enhanced scalability.

Furthermore, it comes in the form of `Sink[ByteString,_]` so it doesn't need further data adaptation/conversion in your case.